# Menu panels show in game by default as open

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm making a 2D game and my Menu panels are showing when i press play on unity they show as opened is there anyway to make them closed and only show when i press on menu button. this is the picture from the game:

[image: menu open]

And this is the script for panel opener when i press the menu button:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PanelOpener : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Panel;


    public void OpenPanle()
    {

        if (Panel != null)
        {

            bool isActive = Panel.activeSelf;
            Panel.SetActive(!isActive);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do Panel.SetActive(false); in Awake()?

Comment: where do i put that because i have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable panels at start with a:

```
    private void Awake(){
        Panel.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Complete code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PanelOpener : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Panel;

    private void Awake(){
        Panel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OpenPanle()
    {

        if (Panel != null)
        {

            bool isActive = Panel.activeSelf;
            Panel.SetActive(!isActive);

        }
    }
}
```

Get yourself familiar with MonoBehaviour functions like Start, Awake, Update, FixedUpdate in the future.

Comment: I will do thanks for the advice and yeah the code worked. it was working fine before i just don't know what happened it started showing as default open. thank you for your answer.